# Print Multiple Pages From a UWA

Tags: c#, printing, win-universal-app, printdocument, .net-4.6

I have about 8 records that I want to print in one batch, each on a separate page. However, the UWP sample for this uses over 600 lines of code to accomplish it. It seems to me that it has to be much, much easier than that. I thought all we'd have to do is add each page to the `PrintDocument` and send the print job. Apparently not. I'm using this:

```
async void Print()
{
    var printDocument = new PrintDocument();
    var printDocumentSource = printDocument.DocumentSource;
    var printMan = PrintManager.GetForCurrentView();
    printMan.PrintTaskRequested += PrintTaskRequested;

    var pages = new List<Page>();

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        (//Set up variables)

        var printPage = new PageToPrint() { //Set properties };
        printPage.Set_Up();  //Set up fields

        pages.Add(printPage);
    }

    printDocument.SetPreviewPage(1, page);
    printDocument.SetPreviewPageCount(pages.Count, PreviewPageCountType.Final);

    foreach (var page in pages)
    {
        printDocument.AddPage(page);
    }

    printDocument.AddPagesComplete();
    await PrintManager.ShowPrintUIAsync();
}

void PrintTaskRequested(PrintManager sender, PrintTaskRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    PrintTask printTask = null;
    printTask = e.Request.CreatePrintTask("Kimble Print Job", sourceRequested =>
    {
        printTask.Completed += PrintTask_Completed;
        sourceRequested.SetSource(printDocumentSource);
    });
}

private async void PrintTask_Completed(PrintTask sender, PrintTaskCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        PrintManager printMan = PrintManager.GetForCurrentView();
        printMan.PrintTaskRequested -= PrintTaskRequested;
    });
}
```

However, it won't generate the print preview. It just sits there spinning and spinning, and if I hit "print" it doesn't succeed (PDF can't open, job never gets to a physical printer.)

I was hoping printing would be at least *reasonably* easy with the `PrintDocument`, and I still think it looks like it should be. Am I just missing it here, or does it really take 600+ lines of code to dispatch a simple print job?

Comment: What are the `items` in your code? And what's the `PagetoPrint` class? Is it same with the official sample? If it is same, what's the `SetUp` function? Since the official sample is running well,  more details of your code parts may help solve your issue.

Comment: The items are an array of classes which I use to set `TextBlock`s, etc. (`SetUp`) on the `PageToPrint`, which is a `Page`.

Answer (score 1):

> However, it won't generate the print preview.

This is because the setPreview method `printDocument.SetPreviewPage(1, page);` must be put in `printDocument.GetPreviewPage`event handle. So you should register the event handle firstly. Same with `printDocument.AddPages` event handle.You messed up the event handle register and callback function all in one.Here I do a little change of your code and I tested it works well.

```
protected PrintDocument printDocument;
protected IPrintDocumentSource printDocumentSource;
List<Page> pages = new List<Page>();
Page printPage = new PageToPrint();
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    RegisterForPrinting();
}

private async void BtnPrint_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await PrintManager.ShowPrintUIAsync();       
}

public void RegisterForPrinting()
{
    printDocument = new PrintDocument();
    printDocumentSource = printDocument.DocumentSource;
    pages.Add(printPage);
    printDocument.GetPreviewPage += GetPrintPreviewPage;
    printDocument.AddPages += AddPrintPages;
    PrintManager printMan = PrintManager.GetForCurrentView();
    printMan.PrintTaskRequested += PrintTaskRequested;
}
private void AddPrintPages(object sender, AddPagesEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var page in pages)
    {
        printDocument.AddPage(page);
    }
    printDocument.AddPagesComplete();
}
private void GetPrintPreviewPage(object sender, GetPreviewPageEventArgs e)
{
    printDocument.SetPreviewPage(1, printPage);
    printDocument.SetPreviewPageCount(pages.Count, PreviewPageCountType.Final);
}

void PrintTaskRequested(PrintManager sender, PrintTaskRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    PrintTask printTask = null;
    printTask = e.Request.CreatePrintTask("Kimble Print Job", sourceRequested =>
    {
        printTask.Completed += PrintTask_Completed;
        sourceRequested.SetSource(printDocumentSource);
    });
}

private async void PrintTask_Completed(PrintTask sender, PrintTaskCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        PrintManager printMan = PrintManager.GetForCurrentView();
        printMan.PrintTaskRequested -= PrintTaskRequested;
    });
}
```

Although you may not need all the code of the sample, but I recommend you to follow the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing) structure and build a PrintHelper class.

Comment: This *looks* like what I wanted, but unfortunately it doesn't even come close to working. It won't allow you to preview anything but the first page, doesn't actually print, etc.

Comment: @RareNCool Yes, this code can just see firstpage because of this code `printDocument.SetPreviewPage(1, printPage);` I just change code based on your code,this not all the features. If you want to implement your all features,please give me all your code, and I try to find a simple solving for you, otherwise, I recommend you to use the sample's code, which doesn't have much extra code.